# C# to F# - EF Code First

Tags: c#, entity-framework, f#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1

I'm having a one-to-many relationship between `Dealer` who can have many `Cars`.

I'm trying to convert my C# code thats used for EF to F#... The problem is just that in my F# code it can fine get a Dealer, but it wont for that Dealer... it just returns null, but in the C# version it works?

My code:

**The C# version**

```
public class Dealer
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Car> Cars { get; set; }

    public Dealer()
    {
        Cars = new List<Car>();
    }
}
public class Car
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string CarName { get; set; }
    public Dealer Dealer { get; set; }
    public int DealerId { get; set; }

    public Car()
    {
        Dealer = new Dealer();
    }
}
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Dealer> Dealers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Car> Cars { get; set; }
    public MyContext()
    {
        Database.Connection.ConnectionString = "server=some;database=dbname;user id=uid;password=pwd";
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Dealer>()
            .HasMany(x => x.Cars)
            .WithRequired(x => x.Dealer)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.DealerId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Car>()
            .HasRequired(x => x.Dealer)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.DealerId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Dealer>().ToTable("Dealers");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Car>().ToTable("Cars");
    }
}
```

... Program.cs which query for dealer and his cars:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var ctx = new MyContext();
    foreach (var s in ctx.Dealers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == 1).Cars)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s.CarName);
    }

    Console.Read();
}
```

**The F# version**

```
type Dealer() =
    let mutable id = 0
    let mutable name = ""
    let mutable cars = List<Car>() :> ICollection<Car>
    member x.ID with get() = id and set v = id <- v
    member x.Name with get() = name and set v = name <- v
    abstract member Cars : ICollection<Car> with get, set
    override x.Cars with get() = cars and set v = cars <- v
and Car() =
    let mutable id = 0
    let mutable carName = ""
    let mutable dealer = Dealer()
    let mutable dealerId = 0
    member x.ID with get() = id and set v = id <- v
    member x.CarName with get() = carName and set v = carName <- v
    member x.Dealer with get() = dealer and set v = dealer <- v
    member x.DealerId with get() = dealerId and set v = dealerId <- v


type MyContext() =
    inherit DbContext("server=some;database=dbname;user id=uid;password=pwd")

    [<DefaultValue>] val mutable dealers : DbSet<Dealer>
    member x.Dealers with get() = x.dealers and set v = x.dealers <- v

    [<DefaultValue>] val mutable cars : DbSet<Car>
    member x.Cars with get() = x.cars and set v = x.cars <- v

    override x.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder:DbModelBuilder) =
        modelBuilder.Entity<Dealer>()
            .HasMany(ToLinq(<@ fun ka -> ka.Cars @>))
            .WithRequired(ToLinq(<@ fun sk -> sk.Dealer @>))
            .HasForeignKey(ToLinq(<@ fun fg -> fg.DealerId @>)) |> ignore

        modelBuilder.Entity<Car>()
            .HasRequired(ToLinq(<@ fun ak -> ak.Dealer @>))
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(ToLinq(<@ fun ka -> ka.DealerId @>)) |> ignore

        modelBuilder.Entity<Dealer>().ToTable("Dealers")
        modelBuilder.Entity<Car>().ToTable("Cars")
```

... The function ToLinq:

```
let ToLinq (exp : Expr<'a -> 'b>) = 
    let linq = exp.ToLinqExpression() 
    let call = linq :?> MethodCallExpression
    let lambda = call.Arguments.[0] :?> LambdaExpression 
    Expression.Lambda<Func<'a, 'b>>(lambda.Body, lambda.Parameters)
```

... And Program.fs which will get the Dealer and his Cars:

```
let ctx = new MyContext()
let joe = ctx.Dealers.Find(1)
joe.Cars |> Seq.iter(fun x -> printfn "%s" x.CarName)
printfn "DONE"
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I don't know anything about EF, but I see that in the F# version `Dealer.Cars` is a virtual property while in the C# version it is just a plain property. Does it make any difference if you change this in F#?

Comment: @wmeyer - fault from my side. The `Dealer.Cars` should also be virtual in the C# version - the only thing that will change is that the collection will now lazy load in c#, which it does fine too (just tested).

Comment: I'm sure this is not an important difference, but your C# doesn't call DBContext(str) while your F# version does?

Comment: @Robert Jeppesen - as you said, then its not an important difference. The reason for why I'm not calling `DbContext(str)` in the C# version, is simply that it cant. I've also tried to define the connectionString the same way as in the C# version, with same result. - Please note that it can without problems connect to the database and get a `Dealer`, the problem first occur when I try to get the Cars for that Dealer.

Comment: public MyContext() : base("connstring") should work?

Comment: @Robert Jeppesen - Touché.. it's unbelievable how fast you forget basic c# knowledge ;p - But yes you're absolutely right.

Comment: @Ebb - I know. I'd rather not have to go back to C#, but I have to, almost daily. :)(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
let mutable cars = List<Car>() :> ICollection<Car>
```

to

```
let mutable cars = Unchecked.defaultof<ICollection<Car>>
```

and

```
let mutable dealer = Dealer()
```

to

```
let mutable dealer = Unchecked.defaultof<Dealer>
```

Comment: This actually works, which I think is strange. The C# version also initializes these properties, but that works? Any insight as to why?

Comment: it works perfectly! Do you know why I need to do `Unchecked.defaultof<>` to activate the ICollection and Dealer?

Comment: F# is `field initialized`   C# is `property initialized`  it is deffirent

Answer (score 1):

To check whether the LINQ expression is the problem, you could try to create such an expression manually.
The following F# code tries to mimic the code that you can see with Reflector or ILSpy in the C# code:

```
open System
open System.Linq.Expressions

// Manually creates a LINQ expression that represents: << x => x.propName >>
// 'T: type of x
// 'C: return type of the property    
let createPropertyGetDelegate<'T, 'C> propName =
   let typ = typeof<'T> // '
   let parameterExpr = Expression.Parameter(typ, "x")
   let getMethod = typ.GetProperty(propName).GetGetMethod()
   let propExpr = Expression.Property(parameterExpr, getMethod)
   Expression.Lambda<Func<'T, 'C>>(propExpr, [|parameterExpr|])


type Example() =
  member x.Test = 42

let del = createPropertyGetDelegate<Example, int> "Test"
printfn "%A" <| del.Compile().Invoke( Example() )
```

Comment: the `ToLinq` method works fine. The problem seems to be that the `Dealer.Cars` property is not getting initialized. @newcommer seems to have found the solution :) - but thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be with your F# `ToLinq` function. It looks like you're just converting an F# anonymous function into a `MethodCallExpression` and having the expression tree act like it should call your function. This is not the same as a "real" expression tree with a `MemberAccessExpression` or whatever it turns out to be from the C# side.

I think EF wants the expression tree in a more semantic fashion so that it can discover the actual property access rather than a simple "fake" method invocation that you're doing here.

My advice would be to crack open Reflector on the two compiled assemblies and see where the difference lies in the Expression trees. Then make the F# code build the same type of expression tree.

**Disclaimer:** I'm not well versed in F# but I'd like to be :). This looks cool!

Comment: I'll give it a shot and return with the result! :=)

Comment: On a completely unrelated matter; where did you pick up the F# syntax from? Any nice tutorial site you've found?

Comment: Don Syme's book Expert F# 2.0 is an excellent reference. It's a little pricey but worth getting. Jon Skeet and Thomas Petricek put together a decent book titled Real-World Functional Programming With Examples in F# and C# which is great for learning how to use functional programming in real-world situations, but isn't a great language reference. I'd recommend the former over the latter, but both are good.

Comment: I'm not able to open Reflector and compare the `OnModelCreating` method since the compiler will serialize the F# Exprs. - Regarding the question about where I picked up the F# syntax, then its mostly just http://fsharp.net and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233154.aspx that have kicked me in the direction.